# pause function not working in script that worked in previous server CentOS 9

Tags: bash, function, variables, include

I have been using the Pause function that is in the thread:

[What is the Linux equivalent to DOS pause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92802/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-to-dos-pause)

I did a fresh install of CentOS 9 and tried to run the scripts that I built using the

```
# !/bin/bash

 source variables.sh

`function pause(){
    read -p "$*"
}`
```

I get this error message now:

```
 : No such file or directoryariables.sh

'/pac-installv8: command substitution: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `{
'/pac-installv8: command substitution: line 18: `function pause(){
```

I have run the yum update -q -y for the OS to see if that fixed the function but it did not. 
The source variables.sh file that I am including is giving a file not found error even though I can use that same variable.sh file in a  test script from the same root folder and it runs just find

```
#!/bin/bash/

source variables.sh
echo "dbuser=$dbuser"
```

This works just find with no errors on the same server. I figure it has to be an OS issue but don't know where to begin to look. Thanks for any help.

Sherwin

Comment: Your script has carriage returns (note the leading quote in the errors). Run `dos2unix` on the script file.

Comment: Glenn you hit it dead on the head. I did not think about that. I copied the files from a windows machine that I wrote them on to a Unix machine and forgot to convert them. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is from your `source` command.  Where did `variables.sh` come from?  You probably need to use the full path name.

Your first line has an error, there should not be a space between the `#` and the `!`, it should be `#!/bin/bash` (optional space *after* the `!`).

The backticks are unnecessary around the function, and the syntax is either:

```
function pause { ... }
```

or

```
pause() { ... }
```

not both, although that should not generate an error.

Comment: the variables.sh is in the same folder as the script.